# Where are stored filter params in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to export the products catalog after I applied a filter. I made a custom button for this, but in the query I need the filters already applied on the grid. Is it possible to get them from the global variable? I noticed that if I refresh the page, the filters are kept, but I do not know where they are from.

Answer (score 0):

You can find applied filters data at the ui_bookmark table of your database;

```
SELECT `namespace`, `config` FROM `ui_bookmark`;
```